# Why does a global buffer variable produce different results than a local buffer variable when using SPI?

Tags: c++, arduino, global-variables

Ok, long-time developer but with higher-order languages like `C#` and `Swift`.  Working in native `C++` for a hardware project I'm working on, and using Arduino for prototyping it. However, this has me stumped.

I have a buffer that I'm sending out over SPI that I currently have defined as a local variable, but when I move it out to global scope, I'm getting different results!

This works as expected...

```
void writeRow(uint8_t row){

    uint8_t buffer[] = {
        B01111111 ^ 0xFF,
        B00111111 ^ 0xFF,
        B00111111 ^ 0xFF,
        B00011111 ^ 0xFF,
        B00001111 ^ 0xFF,
        B00000111 ^ 0xFF,
        B00000011 ^ 0xFF,
        B00000001 ^ 0xFF
    };

    uint16_t rowMask = 1 << row;

    digitalWrite(PIN_LATCH, LOW);

    SPI.transfer16(rowMask); SPI.transfer(buffer,     2);
    SPI.transfer16(rowMask); SPI.transfer(buffer + 2, 2);
    SPI.transfer16(rowMask); SPI.transfer(buffer + 4, 2);
    SPI.transfer16(rowMask); SPI.transfer(buffer + 6, 2);

    digitalWrite(PIN_LATCH, HIGH);
}
```

But this one does not.  Moving the buffer to global level here now sends all zeroes to the SPI bus.

```
uint8_t buffer[] = {
    B01111111 ^ 0xFF,
    B00111111 ^ 0xFF,
    B00111111 ^ 0xFF,
    B00011111 ^ 0xFF,
    B00001111 ^ 0xFF,
    B00000111 ^ 0xFF,
    B00000011 ^ 0xFF,
    B00000001 ^ 0xFF
};

void writeRow(uint8_t row){

    uint16_t rowMask = 1 << row;

    digitalWrite(PIN_LATCH, LOW);

    SPI.transfer16(rowMask); SPI.transfer(buffer,     2);
    SPI.transfer16(rowMask); SPI.transfer(buffer + 2, 2);
    SPI.transfer16(rowMask); SPI.transfer(buffer + 4, 2);
    SPI.transfer16(rowMask); SPI.transfer(buffer + 6, 2);

    digitalWrite(PIN_LATCH, HIGH);
}
```

So what am I missing? That buffer has to be reachable/updateable by several functions, hence wanting to move it out globally.

If this is wrong, what's the correct way to do this?

---

#### Update (and op-ed!)

I misunderstood the Arduino API.  The culprit was I made the incorrect assumption that this version of 'transfer' worked exactly like all the other versions, just this used a buffer vs sending `uint8_t`s individually.

However--and this was in the docs so this is technically on me--***unlike all the other overloads of the same function*** which send things out one or two bytes at a time, then returns the incoming data, the version that takes a buffer ****overwrites that buffer with the incoming data****, thus it was trashing my global buffer the first time it went out.

I personally think this is an *incredibly* poor decision on those who designed the SPI library for Arduino because *other overloads of the same function* do *not* modify your outgoing data, and nothing in the name indicates that this version would work any differently. To the contrary, it looks like if you already have your data in a buffer, it's a much simpler way to send it out.

Because it has this unexpected side-effect behavior, in my opinion, it should have been named something different to be more clear that it is modifying your input data, something fundamentally different than the other overloads.  That or at least adding an extra parameter saying you also wanted the incoming data. In my case, I don't want or need it. It's outbound-only.

Anyway, sorry for the distraction. Hopefully this will still be helpful to the SO community and be a good lesson to always read the docs, even when you think something is obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cannot read'?  Are you getting a compiler error?  If so, what is it?

Comment: No, I'm getting different output sent to my display.  Compiles just fine.  I'll add more code...

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but binary literals should start with `0b` (or `0B`).

Comment: That `buffer` is global in the second example.  Something could be messing it up, unlike the first example where `buffer` is local and safe.

Comment: Arduino uses Bxxx but I'll change it just to be sure. (Update: Didn't make a difference. Same thing.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, nothing else is referencing it, yet.  Above is almost the entire file.  Plus, I just changed the variable name bc of another commenter which would ensure nothing else is touching it.  Didn't work.

Comment: It's definitely not.  writeRow is called from writeScreen which is called from the main loop.  This is why I'm stumped.  Do I have to do a forward declare or something?  Could it be stack vs. heap-related?  I'm literally in the dark on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in various comments and the question update, this is not an issue with C++, but with a misunderstanding of the `SPI` API.

The issue is that `SPI.transfer`'s overload taking a buffer pointer and size as argument does still do bidirectional transfer as other overloads do, but instead of returning transferred data in the way other overloads do, it overwrites the out-going buffer with the incoming data.

Therefore, if `buffer` is global, the second and later calls to `writeRow` will send the previously received data rather than the data from the initialization. With a local `buffer` this doesn't happen because each call to `writeRow` initializes a new `buffer` with the content of the hard-coded initializer.

[See the Arduino documentation for `SPI.transfer`.](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPITransfer)

Comment: Revisiting this and had a thought.  Not in front of my micro controller at present so I can't test, but do you see any down-side to simply connecting the MOSI "out" pin to the MISO "in" pin on the MCU directly?  In theory, that means the outgoing buffer would be 'fed back in' to the MISO pin, thus overwriting itself with itself.  Yes, it's a needless re-write of the data that's essentially a no-op, but logically, it makes sense, no?  Granted, the reason I was trying to use buffers was to move as much as I could to HW and as this is the Arduino API, not hw, it may not matter. Still, I wonder.

Comment: @MarqueIV As I mentioned in a different comment, I don't actually have any experience with this stuff. I just looked at the documentation when I saw your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are building this with the Arduino GUI/IDE/whatever-you-want-to-call-it. The thing to remember is that the the GUI does some preprocessing to what you feed it.

Comment: That's not the case.  Arduino shows you all the output from the compiler.  Confirmed by changing the variable name anyway, just to be sure.  It's something I'm doing wrong in C++, not Arduino, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: You said "cannot read it". Now you say that you get the wrong values. Which one is it?

Comment: Well if I'm getting the wrong values, then I'm not reading them, hence I said that.  I don't see the difference.  I'm getting all zeroes.  Is that a bad read or a good read of bad data?

Comment: Assuming nothing else in your code is trashing the contents of `buffer` when in global space, the only difference would be where in memory it is stored (stack vs. heap). Which board are you writing this for?

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is that the global buffer is initialized once.

If you are overwriting it with another function to set the values to zero then they are going to stay at zero.

On the other hand the buffer in the function will be re-initialized to those specified values every time you enter the function `writeRow()` therefore you will always get the expected values written to the SPI bus.

It looks like to me that you have overwritten the values in the buffer at some point. Print out the values in the buffer before sending them to make sure you are getting the values in the buffer.

Comment: No, that's not the case.  I'm not currently updating it.  That's the plan going forward, but nothing's currently doing it.  I just posted the entire file.  See for yourself.

Comment: @MarqueIV As I mentioned, I don't know Arduino, [but the docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPITransfer) say that `SPI.transfer` replaces the buffer contents. Are you sure this isn't the issue?

Comment: Crap!  That's it!  The buffer version replaces the outgoing with the incoming!! You found it!  That also explains some other anomalies we were seeing.  Not sure how I missed that.  Great find!

Comment: Hey @uneven_mark, mind updating your answer to specifically reference it was an `SPI.transfer` related thing when using buffers and my buffer being global just surfaced that as the culprit?  People may not read all the comments, but you were correct in finding that was the issue.  I've also amended my original question with a commentary on why I feel that was a *horrible* decision by the Arduino SPI library creators to name it that.

Comment: @MarqueIV It is not my answer, I just commented on it because it was the correct fundamental explanation with your mistaken response to it and I didn't feel confident enough to make it an answer. I might later if noone else amends theirs. Actually you could probably just paste your update as answer as well.

Comment: @uneven_mark, you're right! Missed that! it's not yours.  But... you should answer it bc that's how you build up rep here and you did find it.  If I post it as an answer, you don't get the reputation boost.  You should do it!  Just post an answer calling out the issue in the docs.